# Isolation of environments in a shared databricks cluster

Tags: databricks

If a shared cluster is being used by development team in Databricks, how is isolation done to ensure that one developer does not impact another developer's work by installing a particular package. Does CONDA help in isolation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're working on Databricks you have multiple levels of libraries ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/index.html)):

- Cluster level libraries that are installed using cluster UI or REST API - these libraries are shared by all users of the cluster
- For [Python](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/notebooks-python-libraries.html) & [R](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/notebooks-r-libraries.html) there is support for notebook-level libraries. For Python, libraries installed with `%pip install` are installed to a virtual environment specific to a given notebook. So different users can install different libraries or different versions of the same library on the same cluster without breaking other's work.